# MySQL use GROUP_CONCAT when INSERTing data

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, group-concat

I can't find this on Google. I want to insert into one table the combined information from two columns from a different table. I tried it with the following query, but no luck. What mistake did I make, and is there a better way? How can I make a query like this work?

```
INSERT INTO newsitem ('id', 'title', 'body') 
VALUES (10, 'Hello world', GROUP_CONCAT(select date, body FROM blog);
```

<sub>Note: Value names have been changed to protect the innocent.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO newsitem ('id', 'title', 'body') 
SELECT 10 AS `id`, 'Hello world' AS title, GROUP_CONCAT(date, body) AS body FROM blog GROUP BY date, body
```

Your use of `GROUP_CONCAT` is incorrect, it works inside a `SELECT` query. You may go through the complete [INSERT ... SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).